# Тут тут знак

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Разговорное:

-Ты тут? 
-Тут( )тут.

Должен ли стоять знак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Ты тут? -Тут,тут. Повторяющиеся слова.

Comment: "Ты замёрз?" - 1) "Чуть, чуть"; 2) "Чуть - чуть". Комментарий в стиле Дерзкого.

Comment: Чуть - чуть- не повторяющиеся слова, а одно сложное слово - наречие, образованное повтором корней.

Comment: Вынужден согласиться. Но есть тайное желание обратиться в Страссбургский (одно "с" или два?) суд.

Comment: Страсбургский -одно "с". А что это Вас в европейский суд потянуло? Я вроде бы государственное мнение не представляю и против России ничего не имею.Нельзя обойтись статусом пониже?

Comment: Бывает, что и пропадают статьи на Вики,но там тогда написано: "статья не проверена", тогда верить опасно. Проверенные вроде не пропадают.